# Clojure tools.analyzer - identifying last leaf node?

Tags: clojure, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm struggling to come up with a reliable solution to a problem I'm having using tools.analyzer.

What I'm trying to achieve is, given an ast node, what is the last/furthest node in the tree? E.g. If the following code were analayzed: (def a (do (+ 1 2) 3))

Is there a reliable way of marking the node that has the value "3" as the last node in this tree? Essentially what I'm attempting to do is work out which form will eventually be bound to the var b.

Comment: This is a much more complicated goal than your simple question shows. If you want to know which form will be bound to `a`, you don't want "the last leaf in the tree". Consider `(def a (+ 1 2))`. Would you say that `2` is what will be bound to `a`? Of course not! So before you can solve your problem, you need to decide more formally what your actual goal is.

Comment: Please clarify the question re `var b`.

Answer (score -1):

Questions like the above are the reason I created the `tupelo.forest` library a few years ago.

You may wish to view:

- The [home page of the lib](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc)
- The [API docs](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.forest.html)
- The [Clojure/Conj talk](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM)
- Many [live examples](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.clj)

To get started, lets add the data as a tree, after putting it into `hiccup` format.  Here is an outline of how to proceed, with unit tests showing the result of the operations:

```
(ns tst.tupelo.forest-examples
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.forest tupelo.test))

(dotest-focus
  (hid-count-reset)
  (with-forest (new-forest)
    (let [data-orig     (quote (def a (do (+ 1 2) 3)))
          data-vec      (unlazy data-orig)
          root-hid      (add-tree-hiccup data-vec)
          all-paths     (find-paths root-hid [:** :*])
          max-len       (apply max (mapv #(count %) all-paths))
          paths-max-len (keep-if #(= max-len (count %)) all-paths)]
```

Here is the result:

```
      (is= data-vec (quote [def a [do [+ 1 2] 3]]))
      (is= (hid->bush root-hid)
        (quote
          [{:tag def}
           [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw, :value a}]
           [{:tag do}
            [{:tag +}
             [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw, :value 1}]
             [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw, :value 2}]]
            [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw, :value 3}]]]))
      (is= all-paths
        [[1007]
         [1007 1001]
         [1007 1006]
         [1007 1006 1004]
         [1007 1006 1004 1002]
         [1007 1006 1004 1003]
         [1007 1006 1005]])
      (is= paths-max-len
        [[1007 1006 1004 1002]
         [1007 1006 1004 1003]])
      (nl)
      (is= (format-paths paths-max-len)
        (quote [[{:tag def}
                 [{:tag do} [{:tag +} [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw, :value 1}]]]]
                [{:tag def}
                 [{:tag do} [{:tag +} [{:tag :tupelo.forest/raw, :value 2}]]]]])))))
```

Depending on your specific goal, you can continue the processing further.